How to fully remove a Windows EventLog, EventSource and corresponding entries to start over?
I face the following issue:
I created an EventLog and EventSource using this Ansible task:
- name: Add event log with source for auto-shutdown script
  community.windows.win_eventlog:
    name: "ORG-Internal"
    sources:
      - "WindowsAutoShutdown"
    maximum_size: 4MB
    overflow_action: OverwriteAsNeeded
    state: present

I then decided that the EventLog name should better just be "ORG". I modified the Ansible task accordingly. Before running it again, I removed the previous EventLog with this Ansible task:
- name: Remove ORG-Internal log and all remaining sources
  community.windows.win_eventlog:
    name: "ORG-Internal"
    state: absent

This created the new Eventlog and it is shown in the Windows EventViewer. However, no events are being logged from my PowerShell script (using Write-EventLogEntry), where I changed the name of the EventLog to ORG. And before (with "ORG-Internal") it worked correctly.
Furthermore, for testing, I created a completely new EventLog and EventSource like so (note the postfix "New"):
- name: Add event log with source for auto-shutdown script
  community.windows.win_eventlog:
    name: "ORGNew"
    sources:
      - "WindowsAutoShutdownNew"
    maximum_size: 4MB
    overflow_action: OverwriteAsNeeded
    state: present

Logging works correctly in this case after updating my PowerShell script accordingly.
I suspect that there is some "residual" configuration left from creating the first EventLog ("ORG-Internal"), which prevents the new one from functioning correctly. More specifically, I suspect that it may have to do with the EventSource having the same name in both examples (I do not want to change it).
I have also tried using PowerShell commands Remove-EventLog and Clear-EventLog to remove both the old EventLog and EventSource, but this did not help. (But perhaps I did it incorrectly.)
What could be causing this kind of behavior?
